# Nginx response 200 insted of php 301

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

We are using nginx, php-fpm and prestashop 1.5.  Which has a redirect in FrontController. But problem is nginx response status 200 instead of 301.
http://www.bertal.ru/index.php?a1948053/zoddex.ru/123-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5

```
protected function canonicalRedirection($canonical_url = '')
    {
            if (!$canonical_url || !Configuration::get('PS_CANONICAL_REDIRECT') || strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'GET' || Tools::getValue('live_edit'))
                    return;

            $match_url = (Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && ($this->ssl || Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE')) ? 'https://' : 'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $match_url = rawurldecode($match_url);
            if (!preg_match('/^'.Tools::pRegexp(rawurldecode($canonical_url), '/').'([&?].*)?$/', $match_url))
            {
                    $params = array();
                    $str_params = '';
                    $url_details = parse_url($canonical_url);

                    if (!empty($url_details['query']))
                    {
                            parse_str($url_details['query'], $query);
                            foreach ($query as $key => $value)
                                    $params[Tools::safeOutput($key)] = Tools::safeOutput($value);
                    }
                    $excluded_key = array('isolang', 'id_lang', 'controller', 'fc', 'id_product', 'id_category', 'id_manufacturer', 'id_supplier', 'id_cms');
                    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
                            if (!in_array($key, $excluded_key) && Validate::isUrl($key) && Validate::isUrl($value))
                                    $params[Tools::safeOutput($key)] = Tools::safeOutput($value);

                    $str_params = http_build_query($params, '', '&');
                    if (!empty($str_params))
                            $final_url = preg_replace('/^([^?]*)?.*$/', '$1', $canonical_url).'?'.$str_params;
                    else
                            $final_url = preg_replace('/^([^?]*)?.*$/', '$1', $canonical_url);

                    // Don't send any cookie
                    Context::getContext()->cookie->disallowWriting();

                    if (defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_') && _PS_MODE_DEV_ && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != __PS_BASE_URI__)
                            die('[Debug] This page has moved<br />Please use the following URL instead: <a href="'.$final_url.'">'.$final_url.'</a>');

                    header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', true);
                    //header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
                    Tools::redirectLink($final_url);
            }
    }
```

in Tools::redirectLink

```
/**
    * Redirect URLs already containing PS_BASE_URI
    *
    * @param string $url Desired URL
    */
    public static function redirectLink($url)
    {
            if (!preg_match('@^https?://@i', $url))
            {
                    if (strpos($url, __PS_BASE_URI__) !== false && strpos($url, __PS_BASE_URI__) == 0)
                            $url = substr($url, strlen(__PS_BASE_URI__));
                    if (strpos($url, 'index.php?controller=') !== false && strpos($url, 'index.php/') == 0)
                            $url = substr($url, strlen('index.php?controller='));
                    $explode = explode('?', $url);
                    $url = Context::getContext()->link->getPageLink($explode[0]);
                    if (isset($explode[1]))
                            $url .= '?'.$explode[1];
            }
            header('Location: '.$url, true, 301);
            exit;
    }
```

nginx conf

```
server {
access_log off;
error_log  /home/zoddex/logs/zoddex.com-error.log warn;

listen 80;
server_name  zoddex.ru www.zoddex.ru;
root /home/zoddex/public_html;
    rewrite ^/(?!admin4931)(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
index index.php index.html;
client_max_body_size 200m;

location / {

client_max_body_size 200m;
index index.php;
rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

#auth_basic "Restricted Test Site";
#auth_basic_user_file /home/zoddex/public_html/.htpasswd;
}

location ~ \.tpl$ {
  deny all;
}

location  ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
expires 7d;

rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

add_header Cache-Control "public";
access_log off;
}

location ~ ^/js($|/.*) {
   alias /home/zoddex/public_html/js$1;
   expires 7d;
   add_header Cache-Control private;
   access_log off;
}

location ~ ^/css($|/.*) {
   alias /home/zoddex/public_html/css$1;
   expires 7d;
   add_header Cache-Control private;
   access_log off;
}

location ~* ^/(favicon.ico|robots.txt)$ {
   access_log off;
   log_not_found off;
}

error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|ico|swf)$ {
  expires 7d;
  add_header Cache-Control private;
  access_log off;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

location ~ \.php$ {
  root /home/zoddex/public_html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST $host;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure, PHP sends 301?

Comment: I am sure what method `canonicalRedirection` running.

Comment: Turn on logs and check [`$upstream_status`](http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_status)

Comment: The `$upstream_status` return 301, but after nginx redirect with 200

`[20/Jul/2015:18:46:20 +0000] 93.80.174.216 - - - zoddex.ru  to: unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock: GET /123-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5 HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.017 msec 1437417980.649 request_time 0.017 301
`
`[20/Jul/2015:18:46:21 +0000] 93.80.174.216 - - - zoddex.ru  to: unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock: GET /123-noski-detskie HTTP/1.1 upstream_response_time 0.640 msec 1437417981.300 request_time 0.640 200
`

Comment: Nginx responded with 301 redirect and browser made new request. Don't see any problem here

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!